# Attribute is missing namespace prefix

Tags: android

I am having the namespace prefix in my manifest file. Then also it says attribute is missing namespace prefix at the uses-permission line. Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.alarm"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.alarm.MusicPlay"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<uses-permission name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Should be

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`